# Built a partial upload system in Java but Videos are corrupting

Tags: java, android, spring, chunks

So I've built a picture and video partial upload system that seemed to work fine UNTIL we either tried to compress a video or the user tries to play a video. I discovered that writing a video's bytes was not so simple as appending bytes... I'm now (slightly) familiar with concepts such as atoms (free, mov, mdat, uuid, etc) and would like to know why and how a video, which is just a collection of bytes appended to a new file, doesn't recognize that the atoms are still present even though all the bytes are being written.

Anyway here is some source code:

Server Side we have a partial upload object:

```
public class PartialUpload {
    private Integer partialUploadId;
    private String urlSuffix;
    private Date dateAdded;
    private Long expiresIn;
    private Long currentBytesMin;
    private Long currentBytesMax;
    private Long totalBytes;
    private Boolean complete;
    private String filename;

    //there are getters and setters which bind to a database entity below but these are the fields
}
```

Also server side we have the following methods which do the work of checking if the partial upload has started, is being continued, or has reached its total bytes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video_partial", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> postVideoPartial(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam(name = "totalBytes") Long totalBytes) throws IOException {
        PartialUpload upload = new PartialUpload();
        upload.setUrlSuffix(upload.hashUrlSuffix()); // creates a url friendly hash
        Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
        upload.setDateAdded(expiry.getTime());
        expiry.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, PARTIAL_UPLOAD_EXPIRY_TIME); // constant which is a day
        upload.setExpiresIn(expiry.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        upload.setComplete(false);
        upload.setFilename(name);
        upload.setTotalBytes(totalBytes);
        partialUploadRepo.save(upload); //save this object to the database
        PartialUploadInitialDTO dto = new PartialUploadInitialDTO(); //initial DTO which contains the url suffix and the time it expires in
        dto.expiresIn = upload.getExpiresIn();
        dto.urlSuffix = upload.getUrlSuffix();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

//continuing the partial upload until complete
@RequestMapping(value = "/video_partial/{urlSuffix}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> postVideoPartial(@RequestBody byte[] partialBytes, @PathVariable("urlSuffix") String urlSuffix) throws IOException {
        try {
            PartialUpload upload = partialUploadRepo.getUploadByUrlSuffix(urlSuffix);
            if (!upload.isExpired()) {
                if (upload.getComplete() != null && upload.getComplete()) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>("Upload already complete", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                } else {

                    if (upload.getCurrentBytesMin() == null) { //tests if the very first chunk has been sent. If null, the chunk has yet to be sent
                        upload.setCurrentBytesMin(0L); //Tells the client to start at a 0 offset
                        upload.setCurrentBytesMax(START_BYTES_MAX); //Tells the client to upload bytes to the maximum... if there are fewer bytes than the maximum only the applicable bytes will be written
                        if (MediaHelper.initialFileWrite(partialBytes, upload, MediaType.VIDEO)) { //instantiates the file and writes bytes given the file does not yet exist
                            if (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() >= upload.getTotalBytes()) { // if the total bytes have been written
                                if (MediaHelper.moveFileToTempFolder(upload, MediaType.VIDEO)) { //moves the file for compression
                                    PartialUploadCompleteDTO completeDTO = new PartialUploadCompleteDTO();
                                    completeDTO.success = true;
                                    upload.setCurrentBytesMin(upload.getTotalBytes());
                                    upload.setCurrentBytesMax(upload.getTotalBytes());
                                    upload.setComplete(true);
                                    partialUploadRepo.save(upload); //saves that the upload has been completed
                                    return new ResponseEntity<>(completeDTO, HttpStatus.OK); //return success
                                } else {
                                    return new ResponseEntity<>("Couldn't Move File To Temp Folder", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                                }
                            } else {
                                //***************************************
                                PartialUploadInProgressDTO dto = new PartialUploadInProgressDTO(); //case where there are more chunks to upload and where I am receiving error
                                Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
                                expiry.setTime(upload.getDateAdded());
                                expiry.setTimeInMillis(expiry.getTimeInMillis() + upload.getExpiresIn());
                                dto.expirationDateTime = expiry.getTime();
                                dto.nextExpectedMin = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + 1; //offset the next bytes by the last byte written + 1 MAY BE THE CAUSE OF THE ERRORS
                                dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() - upload.getCurrentBytesMin()); // offset the next max by the current max (which is the minimum) plus the interval number of bytes
                                if (dto.nextExpectedMax >= upload.getTotalBytes()) { //if the max overshoots the total bytes make the max the new total bytes
                                    dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getTotalBytes();
                                }
                                upload.setCurrentBytesMin(dto.nextExpectedMin);
                                upload.setCurrentBytesMax(dto.nextExpectedMax);
                                partialUploadRepo.save(upload); // saves the next expected chunk
                               return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                            }
                        } else {
                            return new ResponseEntity<>("Retry", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //appends bytes to the already existing file
                        if (MediaHelper.appendBytesToFile(upload, partialBytes, MediaType.VIDEO)) {
                            if (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() >= upload.getTotalBytes()) { //test if complete (total bytes achieved)
                                if (MediaHelper.moveFileToTempFolder(upload, MediaType.VIDEO)) {
                                    PartialUploadCompleteDTO completeDTO = new PartialUploadCompleteDTO();
                                    completeDTO.success = true;
                                    upload.setCurrentBytesMin(upload.getTotalBytes());
                                    upload.setCurrentBytesMax(upload.getTotalBytes());
                                    upload.setComplete(true);
                                    partialUploadRepo.save(upload); //see above
                                    return new ResponseEntity<>(completeDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
                                } else {
                                    return new ResponseEntity<>("Couldn't Move File To Temp Folder", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                                }
                            } else {
                                PartialUploadInProgressDTO dto = new PartialUploadInProgressDTO();
                                Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
                                expiry.setTime(upload.getDateAdded());
                                expiry.setTimeInMillis(expiry.getTimeInMillis() + upload.getExpiresIn());
                                dto.expirationDateTime = expiry.getTime();
                                dto.nextExpectedMin = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + 1;
                                dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() - upload.getCurrentBytesMin());
                                if (dto.nextExpectedMax >= upload.getTotalBytes()) {
                                    dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getTotalBytes();
                                }
                                upload.setCurrentBytesMin(dto.nextExpectedMin);
                                upload.setCurrentBytesMax(dto.nextExpectedMax);
                                partialUploadRepo.save(upload);
                               return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                            }
                        } else {
                            return new ResponseEntity<>("Retry", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Upload has expired", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No File Exists At URL", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

These are the media helper methods:

```
    public boolean initialFileWrite(byte[] partialBytes, PartialUpload upload, MediaType type) {
        File blobUploadDirectory = null;
        try {
            if (type == MediaType.IMAGE) {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobImageUploadDir();
            } else {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobVideoUploadDir();
            }
            if (!blobUploadDirectory.exists()) {
                blobUploadDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(blobUploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + upload.getFilename());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, partialBytes, false);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //unappend appended bytes
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean appendBytesToFile(PartialUpload upload, byte[] partialBytes, MediaType type) {
        File blobUploadDirectory = null;
        try {
            if (type == MediaType.IMAGE) {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobImageUploadDir();
            } else {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobVideoUploadDir();
            }
            if (!blobUploadDirectory.exists()) {
                blobUploadDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(blobUploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + upload.getFilename());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, partialBytes, true);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //unappend appended bytes
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean moveFileToTempFolder(PartialUpload upload, MediaType type) {
        File blobUploadDirectory = null;
        try {
            if (type == MediaType.IMAGE) {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobImageUploadDir();
            } else {
                blobUploadDirectory = getBlobVideoUploadDir();
            }
            if (!blobUploadDirectory.exists()) {
                blobUploadDirectory.mkdirs();
                return false;
            }
            File file = new File(blobUploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + upload.getFilename());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                return false;
            }
            File outFile = type == MediaType.IMAGE ? new File(getLocalImageUploadDir(), upload.getFilename()) : new File(getLocalVideoUploadDir(), upload.getFilename());
            return file.renameTo(outFile);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //unappend appended bytes
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the mobile application I'm using a modified version of QTFastStart to move the moov atom to the front of the structure (shouldn't be necessary but is a temporary solution). Otherwise the moov atom is corrupted. Any help as to why the atoms are being corrupted in the file transfer process would be much appreciated.

Here is some more source code from the Android Application

```
if (currentMedia.getType() == VIDEO) {
                    try {
                        String newFileName = currentMedia.getPath(); //qualified media path
                        newFileName = newFileName.replaceAll("\\d+\\.mp4", "newFile.mp4"); //makes a temp mp4 for the current media. I tested with AtomicParsley and QTFastStart (PY) to make sure this wasn't the issue

                        File inFile = new File(currentMedia.getPath());
                        File outFile = new File(newFileName);
                        if (!outFile.exists()) {
                            outFile.createNewFile();
                        }
                        QtFastStart.fastStart(inFile, outFile); //moves the moov atom indices
                        outFile.renameTo(new File(currentMedia.getPath())); //makes the original file the moved file
                        file = new File(currentMedia.getPath());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (QtFastStart.MalformedFileException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (QtFastStart.UnsupportedFileException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    file = new File(currentMedia.getPath());
                }
                //reads a total number of bytes from a file
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                } else {
                    fileContent = readFile(file);
                }

                if (currentMedia.getType() == IMAGE) {
                    mediaApiFactory.makeRequestStartImagePartialUpload(file.getName(), fileContent.length).start(null, initialResultListener);
                    pictureProgressText.setText("Uploading " + currentMedia.getName() + ".jpg");

                } else {
                    mediaApiFactory.makeRequestStartVideoPartialUpload(file.getName(), fileContent.length).start(null, initialResultListener);
                    pictureProgressText.setText("Uploading " + currentMedia.getName() + ".mp4");

                }
```

Then I use retrofit to send the video / image to the server

Then I handle the responses

```
if (result != null && result.isSuccess()) {
                PartialUploadInitialDTO dto = result.getData();
                currentUrlSuffix = dto.urlSuffix;
                currentMinBytes = 0;
                currentMaxBytes = START_BYTES_MAX;
                chunks = new ArrayList<>();
                chunks.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, (int)currentMinBytes, (int)currentMaxBytes));

                if (currentMedia.getType() == IMAGE) {
                    mediaApiFactory.makeRequestContinueImagePartialUpload(currentUrlSuffix, chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)).start(null, intermediateResultListener);
                } else {
                    mediaApiFactory.makeRequestContinueVideoPartialUpload(currentUrlSuffix, chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)).start(null, intermediateResultListener);
                }
            }
```

Then the upload is continued until the total bytes are read (success status)

```
if (result != null && result.isSuccess()) {
                if (result.getData() instanceof PartialUploadInProgressDTO) { //contains the success status of a complete dto as well (me being lazy)
                    PartialUploadInProgressDTO dto = (PartialUploadInProgressDTO)result.getData();
                    if (dto.success != null && dto.success) { //denotes that the upload was successful
                        currentFile++;
                        if (currentMedia.isDeleted()) {
                            if (currentMedia.getPath() != null) {
                                MediaUtils.deleteFile(currentMedia.getPath());
                            }
                        }
                        if (mediaInvocationListener != null) {
                            mediaInvocationListener.onUpdateProgress(currentFile, count);
                        }
                        pictureProgressBar.setProgress(100);
                        next();
                    } else { //the upload is still in progress
                        currentMinBytes = dto.nextExpectedMin;
                        currentMaxBytes = dto.nextExpectedMax;
                        chunks.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, (int) currentMinBytes, (int) currentMaxBytes)); //adds the next chunk of bytes
                        int progress = (int)((float)currentMinBytes / fileContent.length * 100);
                        pictureProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

                        if (currentMedia.getType() == IMAGE) {
                            mediaApiFactory.makeRequestContinueImagePartialUpload(currentUrlSuffix, chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)).start(null, intermediateResultListener); //recursive to this method
                        } else {
                            mediaApiFactory.makeRequestContinueVideoPartialUpload(currentUrlSuffix, chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)).start(null, intermediateResultListener); //recursive to this method
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is an average atom tree before and after reaching the server
BEFORE (but after QTQuick has run):

```
ftyp (24 bytes)
moov (15372 bytes)
mdat (67290713 bytes)
```

AFTER (Chunks successfully uploaded)

```
REM This is available upon request looks something like
ftyp (bytes)
moov (bytes)
NOTMDAT(bytes)
```

Anyway sorry for the long winded post. If anything else is needed please ask and I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem which was an error in the code. When bytes have their from and to values, you don't need to account for the last byte being written, you just continue off the same number. So the following was correct:

```
dto.nextExpectedMin = upload.getCurrentBytesMax();
dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() - upload.getCurrentBytesMin());
```

Wherever I had

```
dto.nextExpectedMin = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + 1;
dto.nextExpectedMax = upload.getCurrentBytesMax() + (upload.getCurrentBytesMax() - upload.getCurrentBytesMin());
```

Before